# Laravel 5.1 cannot migrate the database

Tags: php, mysql, mamp, laravel-5.1

Im using MAMP for the web server:

Below is my code
**config/database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'unix_socket'   => '/Application/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=dfsfsdffsd

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=my_database
DB_USERNAME=my_db_username
DB_PASSWORD=my_db_password

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I got this error when run `php artisan migrate`:

```
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

What could possibly wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Did you make the migration? `php artisan make:migration`

Comment: I run `php artisan migrate` in the fresh laravel installation to migrate the users table

Comment: try running this command `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: still got the same error :(

Comment: make sure MySQL is up and running and make sure it is using the default port 3306? Try to connect to mysql from the command line to make sure you can connect to MySQL. Open up a command line the try to connect like this `mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p` and see if you are able to connect. if that does not work you may want to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 or update your hosts file with this line '127.0.0.1     localhost`  and `127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1`

Comment: check one more thing please what is the value of the `default` key in your database.php files located in the config folder? if it is not set to mysql please check it to mysql

Comment: it says `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),`

Comment: please check out my answer below

Answer (score 2):

First try to change your command to this

```
php artisan migrate --env=local
```

If that did not work make sure MySQL is up and running and make sure it is using the default port `3306`.

Additionally, try to connect to MySQL from the command line to make sure you can connect to MySQL. Open up a command line the try to connect like this

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p
```

and see if you are able to connect. If that does not work you may want to change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` or update your hosts file with this line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1
```

I would also add this line to your .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
```

if all the above fails I would say your socket value is not setup correctly.

try changing your socket values from

```
/Application/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

to

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

You may consider creating a php.ini file for PHP

open up php.ini file and look for `pdo_mysql.default_socket` and set is as:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```